# Как правильно обработать на Java входящий JSON?

Tags: java, json

Как делать запросы и их обрабатывать - я разобрался.

А как настроить приложение слушать на определенном порту, не могу разобраться.

В частности, мне нужно сделать обработчик входящего вебхука от Битрикс24.
т.е.

В мануале битрикс сказано:

```
укажите url вашего обработчика в настройках исходящего webhook
https://your_server/your_webhook_script.php


код обработчика

<?php

/*

Битрикс24 передает в обработчик $_REQUEST с данными:

array(
 'PHONE_NUMBER' => '555666777', //номер, на который звонит пользователь Битрикс24
 'USER_ID' => '1', //пользователь, который звонит из интерфейса Битрикс24
 'CRM_ENTITY_TYPE' => 'LEAD', //тип объекта CRM, из карточки которого звонит пользователь Битрикс24
 'CRM_ENTITY_ID' => '248' //ID объекта CRM, из карточки которого звонит пользователь Битрикс24
)
*/
```

Comment: ваш вопрос не понятен, что у вас на сервере? какой json вы получаете, что вы хотите с ним сделать?

Comment: на сервере у меня - ни чего. Суть вопроса, не что я буду делать с json, а как его получить...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам необходима авторизация, аутентификация И так далее, тогда лучше взять готовую реализацию, типа томката, которую вам уже посоветовали.

Если же вас интересует голая(core java) реализация и вы не будете отягощать Ее авторизацией и другими плюшками присущими Java ee, то в Java есть встроенный http сервер без наворотов, в котором у вас будет возможность получить строку с вашим Json, использую его для мини приложений типа выдачи статуса...

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
server.createContext("/json", new JsonHandler())
server.start();

class JsonHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {

        InputStream requestBody = exchange.getRequestBody();
        ...

        OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody();
        ...
        os.close();

    }
}
```

для работы собственно json, лучше велосипед не изобретать а взять что-то, например я бы взял [jackson](https://github.com/codehaus/jackson)

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно!

Comment: Пожалуйста =) Обращайтесь

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно реализовать Java RESTful Web Services. Например на базе TomCat или Jersey.
Почитайте [тут](https://o7planning.org/ru/11199/java-restful-web-services-tutorial-for-beginners), эта статья даст вам примерное понимание вопроса...

Comment: С томкатом я знаком и опыт имею... А вот без Томкатов нельзя?